# How to set rate limit for Traefik Ingress Controller?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

In version 1.5, Traefik just implemented Rate limiting feature https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2034

But I don't know how to use this in Traefik Ingress Controller. Is there any way to set Rate limit by using Annotations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you cannot define rate limit with annotations.
This feature come in v1.6: https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2612